# Ticker with Header and sub-headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I was looking to have a sort of ticker or message display system.

Basically I want an array of headers. for example:

```
var Headers = [
    ["Header 1"],
    ["Header 2"],
    ["Header 3"],
    ["Header 4"]
];
```

Then have an array or numerous arrays for the sub headers related to the initial array. for example:

```
var Messages1 = [
    ["Message1 1"],
    ["Message1 2"],
    ["Message1 3"]
];

var Messages2 = [
    ["Message2 1"],
    ["Message2 2"],
    ["Message2 3"]
];

// etc etc etc
```

What I am trying to achieve is have one div show the header and another div loop through the messages related to that header. Then move to next header and then show the messages related to that header. Hope that makes sense.

The structure of the arrays could probably change if the right solution was provided.

Im sure it has probably been done however I cannot see an example online.

Even if there is one online I am happy to try reverse engineer the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

jmcall10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood your requirement completely, but are you looking for something like this:

```
var headers = [
    {
        header: 'Header1',
        subheaders: [
            'Subheader1',
            'Subheader2',
            '...'
        ]
    },
    {
        header: 'Header2',
        subheaders: [
            'Subheader3',
            'Subheader4',
            '...'
        ]
    }
]
```

If you are worried about duplications of sub-headers, you can move them to separate object:

```
var subheaders = {
    'subheader1': 'Subheader1',
    'subheader2': 'Subheader2',
    'subheader3': 'Subheader3',
    'subheader4': 'Subheader4',
}
```

and have them referenced in the headers array by object keys:

```
var headers = [
    {
        header: 'Header1',
        subheaders: [
            'subheader1',
            'subheader2',
            '...'
        ]
    },
    {
        header: 'Header2',
        subheaders: [
            'subheader1',
            'subheader2',
            '...'
        ]
    }
]
```

**Important note:** Keep in mind that you should set proper naming conventions for keys of the sub-header object. `subheader1`, `subheader2` is probably a poor choice even when used only in an example. :)

**Edit:**

To loop through them first version:

```
headers.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.header);
    item.subheaders.forEach(function (subheader) {
        console.log(subheader);
    });
});
```

It's quite similar for the second version as well:

```
headers.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.header);
    item.subheaders.forEach(function (subheaderKey) {
        if (subheaders.hasOwnKey(subheaderKey)) {
            console.log(subheaders[subheaderKey]);
        }
    });
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: Yes the structure of this looks a lot better than what I had. Do you have any sample code that would loop though the arrays and cycle the subheader section. Perhaps using jQuery. Apologies if this is to much to ask.

Comment: Nice. Good luck!  :-)